# How to choose an appropriate csv file to create a graph in python

Tags: python, csv, graph

I was wondering how to choose a CSV file to create a graph because I chose a CSV file that contains 2 columns for nodes without weight, and I was not sure if it was the correct choice, since I found in the Kaggle dataset a CSV file containing the train data.

Here is the csv file I found in the Stanford university datasets.
[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhxmI.png).
However, I found a train.csv and test.csv file in the Facebook Recruiting Competition.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Appropriate for what?

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how to select a CSV file to create a graph for social networks. I choose a CSV file from Stanford University dataset that contains two columns and use it to create my graph. Is there another file that I should use or no?

Comment: you haven't even told us how you are creating the graph. What kind of graph? Have u successfully created a graph with data generated in ur script? 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example